# Can the "Hardware Version" of an Android phone be changed?

Tags: java, android, version, hardware

When you go to Settings > About Phone on an Android device, it will give you the kernel, software, hardware version, etc.

I'm curious if the Hardware Version will ever actually change on any given phone. I know from prior experience with rooting my phone and updating the ROM/Kernel/Modem that all the other numbers and versions have the ability to change, but i'm fairly confident that the Hardware version tends to stay the same, just need confirmation.

I'm asking because I'm curious about making an app, and then adding specific features to that app for certain phone types, ie a phone that will only display some data to all variants of the galaxy s2 (d710.10) and grabbing this data from android.os.Build.MODEL (or Build.PRODUCT)

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to think if targeting particular hardware irrespective of software is meaningful, since unless you are hacking below the level of the android platform, you primarily get access to the hardware through the software, so anything special you want to do would depend on having system software that supports it much more than on having hardware theoretically capable of being programmed to do it.  (CPU instruction set extension might be a possible exception).  It sounds like maybe you are trying to use the hardware as a shortcut to matching software versions

Comment: Actually its just for reference for a client, trying to figure out the easiest way that we can make sure their own phones will have certain access to content while others won't. I'm sure their tech guys new the answer to this but we've only had contact with low level project managers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those fields are part of the build.prop. The build.prop can be edited on a rooted phone, but otherwise not.